# UIPickerView ignoring contraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, xcode-storyboard

I have a view within my app that has a UIPickerView. The delegation and datasource is set up and the picker loads data correctly, however, it ignores storyboard constraints entirely and shifts to the top of the view regardless of what I've tried.

The screenshots below show the alignment in storyboard (the picker is aligned center vertical/horizontal to the blue view (which has a constraint of 30 on all sides) and the alignment when the app is run on a 6S.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try setting a height and width constraint on the UIPicker as well. Sometimes it also helps to set a background colour to get a better idea of what's going on

Comment: @nanako I gave it a dark blue background and a size of 100x100, see the added photo above. Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you show your @IBOutlet code linked to the UIPicker? Are you setting a frame anywhere in code for the pickerView?

Comment: @Tim I'm not modifying any part of the UI programmatically, this is all I have for the picker: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *mouthpiecePicker;` and  `self.mouthpiecePicker.delegate = self;
    self.mouthpiecePicker.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.mouthpiecePicker];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `[self.view addSubview:self.mouthpiecePicker];` This is re-adding the picker view, but it was already added with Storyboard. When you re-add it, it removed all constraints.

Comment: Actually re-adding the view was not altering its frame property at all, but it WAS removing all constraints...

Comment: @Tim just realized I never responded to this. Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 2):

UIPickerView has a fussy implementation of setFrame:  -it only allows itself to be rendered in a handful of sizes.  The easiest way to control/overcome this is to put it in a container view and apply your constraints to that view. You could override layoutSubviews in that containerView in order to center the picker, perhaps even applying a transform to scale it.  Don't try to set the size of the pickerview in this code, just query (get) it and then calculate around that value.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll take all that into consideration as I continue designing that view.